# IIS 7 Admin pack doesn't want to install on Windows Server 2008 64bits

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I downloaded 64 bits Admin Pack
http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack

When I tried to install on my brand new IIS7 windows server 2008 web version it says it requires iis 7 !

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Admin Pack on Server editions. As you add roles or features the management tools are also installed (or you get the option).

The Admin Pack is for remote management of servers from client editions.

Comment: On client Windows, I also get this message. Do you mean that the client must install ("turn windows features on or off") IIS before it can do this installation http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13092 ?